# Jest test onClick for util function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

Hey guys I am facing issue while trying to add test case for onClick in **MetaDetails.tsx** file

**utils.js**

```
export const handlePrintLabelButtonClick = (
  e,
  rmaNumber,
  labelUrl,
  getReturnLabel
) => {
  const rmaList = [];

  e.preventDefault();
  if (!labelUrl) {
    // some logic
  } else {
    // some logic
  }
};
```

**PrintLabel.tsx**

```
import { DefaultButton } from "some path";
import { AnchorWrapper, ButtonWrapper } from "./index.styles";

export const PrintLabelButton = ({
  target,
  url,
  type,
  text,
  onClickHandle
}: PrintLabelButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <ButtonWrapper>
      <AnchorWrapper
        href={url}
        target={target}
        type={type}
      >
        <DefaultButton
          tabIndex="0"
          onClick={onClickHandle}
          data-test="print-label-button"
        >
          {text}
        </DefaultButton>
      </AnchorWrapper>
    </ButtonWrapper>
  );
};
```

**MetaDetails.tsx**

```
// Some lines of code 
import { PrintLabelButton } from "./printLabel";
import { handlePrintLabelButtonClick } from "utils";
export const OrderMetaDetails = () => {
  // some logic 
  return(
    //Some React code 

    {showPrintLabelButton && (
          <PrintLabelButton
            onClickHandle={e =>
              handlePrintLabelButtonClick(e, rmaNumber, labelUrl, getLabel)
            }
            url={labelUrl}
            target="_blank"
            type="printLabel"
            text={intl.formatMessage(messages.printLabelText)}
            
          />
        )}

      // Some React code 
  )
}
```

What I've tried

**MetaDetails.test.tsx**

```
 test("Order Meta Details Print Label Click", () => {
    const handlePrintLabelButtonClick = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mountWithIntl(
      <OrderMetaDetails
        getLabel={() => {}}
        info={/*some data*/}
        intl={/*intl*/ }
      />
    );
    const component = wrapper.find(`[data-test="print-label-button"]`).hostNodes();
    component.simulate("click")
    expect(handlePrintLabelButtonClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

**Jest throws the following error**

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

When running the test coverage, in the function coverage I see that the "handlePrintLabelButtonClick" in **MetaDetails.tsx** is shown as uncovered. I have tried other approaches as well but none worked. I am new to unit testing. Can someone please guide as to what is the correct approach.

**Note 1:**  I am using react/@emotion
**Note 2:**  I have commented or written text such as "some logic" since there are lots of unwanted lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your source code still uses the original `handlePrintLabelButtonClick` function, not the mock function that you created in the test.

You need to mock the actual exported function, for example using `jest.mock`:

```
import { handlePrintLabelButtonClick } from './utils.js';

const mockHandlePrintLabelButtonClick = jest.fn();
// Mock the module.
jest.mock('./utils.js', () => {
  handlePrintLabelButtonClick: mockHandlePrintLabelButtonClick 
}

describe('something', () => {
  test("Order Meta Details Print Label Click", () => {
    const wrapper = mountWithIntl(
      <OrderMetaDetails
        getLabel={() => {}}
        info={/*some data*/}
        intl={/*intl*/ }
      />
    );
    const component = wrapper.find(`[data-test="print-label-button"]`).hostNodes();
    component.simulate("click")
    expect(mockHandlePrintLabelButtonClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
})
```